# Mysql count Same Two or More Same Record as One and Summarize It

Tags: mysql, count, sum

Good Afternoon all,

I have two same data record or more in MySql table. How i can counting the same data as one and zero if have only one data based on flag status pair. Below is an example of data:

```
GLOBAL_ID        FLAG_STATUS    
VTSA-C-B002      IN
VTSA-C-B002      OUT
VTSA-C-B003      IN
VTSA-C-B031      IN
VTSA-C-B031      OUT
VTSA-C-B031      OUT
VTSA-C-B002      OUT
VTSA-C-B005      OUT
ABCD-D-B004      IN
ABCD-D-B001      IN
ABCD-D-B003      IN
ABCD-D-B001      OUT
ABCD-D-B003      OUT
ABCD-D-B005      IN
```

Then The result as i wanted to counting is looks like here

```
Global ID        Count
VTSA-C-B002      1 (Because have a Pair Flag Status ("IN" AND "OUT")
VTSA-C-B003      0 (Because Dont have a Pair Flag Status ("IN" AND "OUT")
VTSA-C-B031      1
VTSA-C-B005      0
ABCD-D-B004      0
ABCD-D-B001      1
ABCD-D-B003      1
ABCD-D-B005      0
```

so the Final result to Summarize the counting like this,

```
Global_ID ALias      SUM of counting
VTSA                 2
ABCD                 2
```

I have try this query in below, but the result as i looking for

```
SELECT global_id,
       mandays 
FROM ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.global_id) AS mandays,
              CASE WHEN b.global_id like "%ABCD%" THEN 'ABCD' ELSE 'VTSA' END AS global_id 
       FROM she_cii.tb_gate_log b 
       WHERE b.global_id REGEXP 'VTSA|ABCD' 
       AND date(b.received_date)="2024-02-03" 
       AND flag_status IN("IN","OUT") 
       group by SUBSTRING(b.global_id FROM POSITION('-' in b.global_id)+1 FOR 5)
      ) x
```

the result from that query looks like this

```
global_id   mandays
VTSA        36 (counting all distint global id record)
ABCD        45 (counting all distint global id record)
```

Thank You
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your given data example the pairs could easily be found by using

```
select GLOBAL_ID
from she_cii
group by GLOBAL_ID
having min(FLAG_STATUS) = 'IN' and max(FLAG_STATUS) = 'OUT';
```

The result would be

```
GLOBAL_ID
VTSA-C-B002
VTSA-C-B031
ABCD-D-B001
ABCD-D-B003
```

Now per the count you can use an outer query such as

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(GLOBAL_ID,'-',1) as Global_ID_ALias ,
       count(*) as mandays
from ( 
      select  GLOBAL_ID 
      from she_cii
      group by GLOBAL_ID
      having min(FLAG_STATUS) = 'IN' and max(FLAG_STATUS) = 'OUT'
     ) pair
group by Global_ID_ALias;
```

Result

```
Global_ID_ALias mandays
VTSA    2
ABCD    2
```

See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/R5dMC6B_)

---

**Edit**

To speed up the query for the given conditions follow below steps

Date function doesn't use an index if present, replace

```
date(b.received_date)="2024-02-03"
```

with

```
received_date >='2024-02-03' and received_date <'2024-02-04'
```

You are looking for `global_id`  starting with `VTSA` or `ABCD`, replace

```
b.global_id REGEXP 'VTSA|ABCD'
```

with

```
global_id like 'VTSA%' or global_id like 'ABCD%'
```

Final query would be

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(GLOBAL_ID,'-',1) as Global_ID_ALias ,
       count(*) as mandays
from ( 
      select  GLOBAL_ID 
      from she_cii
      group by GLOBAL_ID
      having min(FLAG_STATUS) = 'IN' and max(FLAG_STATUS) = 'OUT'
      where flag_status IN ('IN','OUT')
      and ( global_id like 'VTSA%' or global_id like 'ABCD%')
      and received_date >='2024-02-03' and received_date <'2024-02-04'
     ) pair
group by Global_ID_ALias;
```

Having the `index flgst_glbid_recdt(flag_status ,global_id ,received_date )` will speed up the query.

Comment: hello Ergest.
Great, Thank you for the answer. I never now the having can do that.

for received date i'm not put in on example data because i can use that using Where clause. For REGEXP ' VTSA|OUTOTEC ', there is so many global id format, but i want to calculate some specific global id format.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(global_id, '-', 1) global_id, 
       SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT flag_status) - 1) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(global_id, '-', 1)) mandays
FROM tb_gate_log
GROUP BY global_id;
```

| global_id | mandays |
| --- | --- |
| ABCD | 2 |
| VTSA | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qyv6gRa7)